# Running fredhopper as a service

Tags: smarttarget, fredhopper

Currently after every system restart we are running Fredhopper by starting deployment agent and then starting indexer.

is there any way to configure fredhopper as  a service so that is should restart automatically whenever system restarts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no Windows services delivered with Fredhopper.

Fredhopper recommends using the Windows Task Scheduler to start the deployment agent. They have a [page on their Learning Center](https://www.fredhopper.com/learningcenter/display/learningcenter/Starting+the+deployment+agent+on+boot+%28Windows%29) to help you with that (requires login). That is what I typically do and have not have any issues with it.

There is no mention of the indexer or other processes, but presumably you can use the same mechanism -- but only once the deployment agent is up and running.

You could try other solutions that people have for running any program as a service, such as [NSSM](http://nssm.cc/), [SrvAny](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/137890/en-us?wa=wsignin1.0), etc. I don't know how well they work.